# LUA delete 2 different characters with gsub

Tags: lua, gsub, openresty, lua-patterns

I want to delete two different characters at the beginning and end of my_string with gsub..
But I managed to delete only one..

```
    local my_string  = "[I wish you a happy birthday]"
    local new_string = bouquet:gsub('%]', '')
    print(new_string)
```

How can I create the right gsub pattern?

Comment: If the characters are present, try `my_string:sub(2,-2)`.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this:

```lua
local new_string = my_string:match("^%[(.*)]$")
```

[explanation](https://gitspartv.github.io/lua-patterns/?pattern=%5E%25%5B(.*)%5D$): Match a string that starts with `[` and ends with `]` and return just what's between the two. For any other strings, it will just return them as is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```lua
local new_string = my_string:gsub('^%[(.*)]$', '%1')
```

See [this Lua demo](https://ideone.com/WKfQD9). The `^%[(.*)]$` pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `%[` - a literal `[` char
- `(.*)` - captures any zero or more chars into Group 1 (`%1` refers to this value from the replacement pattern)
- `]` - a `]` char
- `$` - end of string.

Alternatively, you can use

```lua
local new_string = string.gsub(my_string:gsub('^%[', ''), ']$', '')
```

See [this Lua demo online](https://ideone.com/suLanM).

The `^%[` pattern matches a `[` at the start of the string and `]$` matches the `]` char at the end of the string.

If there is no need to check if `[` and `]` positions, just use

```lua
local new_string = my_string:gsub('[][]', '')
```

See the [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/SWdoh9).

The `[][]` pattern matches either a `]` char or a `[` char.

Comment: @bobblebubble This is not a duplicate since the question is not about regex, but about Lua patterns. I replaced the wrong tag.

Comment: "The `[][]` regex matches"—It's a pattern, not a regex ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the basic pattern for gsub, I suggest a easy way to solve you problem.

```
local new_string = my_string:gsub('%]',''):gsub('%[','')
```

Answer (score 0):

So...

```
do
local my_string="[I wish you a happy birthday]"
local new_string=my_string:gsub('[%[%]]','',2)
print(new_string)
end
```

...leads to the desired output. The `%` escapes the `[` and `]` - Like in other languages the `\` do.